# Capture details from http request and response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am setting up a jmeter test plan for http requests and I want to create a table capturing some details from http request and response. I read http request from a file using CSV Data Set Config. My request and response formats are as follows

Http Request Format: `{"TYPE":"<type>", "PAYLOAD": [<Array of data>]}`

Http Response Format: `{"RESPONSE":[<Array of data>]}`

Things I want to capture for each request, response are TYPE from HTTP Request, Array Size of RESPONSE (or Array size of PAYLOAD) and Time Taken.

The jmeter version I am using is v5.2.1. Any inputs on how can I set this up?

Edit: My HTTP request is a POST request. I am looking to capture details from Request Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using JMeter Plugins you can:

1. Declare the variables from the CSV file as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
2. Extract the number of matches from the response using JSON Extractor configured like:

   - Name of created variables: `responsarray`
   - JSON Path expressions: `$.RESPONSE.*`
   - Match Nr.: `-1`

     the variable value you need to declare in the Sample Variables will be `responsearray_matchNr`
3. The above Sample Variables can be saved into a file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

---

If you cannot use the plugin you still can achieve the same using [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) code:

```
def result = new File('result.txt')

def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def requestType = request.TYPE
def requestArray = request.PAYLOAD.size()

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def responseArray = response.RESPONSE.size()
def timeTaken = prev.getTime()

result << requestType << ',' << requestArray << ',' << responseArray << ',' << timeTaken << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```